# Как сформировать запрос к API, если часть параметров статичны, а часть — динамичны?

Tags: javascript, http, google-apps-script, yandex-metrika-api

Нужно сделать скриптик для гуглдока, который бы отсылал GET запрос к API Я.Метрики, в котором половина параметров - статичны, другая половина - динамичны и указываются в виде аргументов пользовательской функции.

Пробовал просто строковое выражение, в которое с помощью шаблонных литералов вставлял динамические параметры, но чёт не пошло. Хотя теоретически, запрос должен был сформироваться верно. В JS не шарю от слова совсем. Есть хороший способ?

Текущий нерабочий вариант:

```
function GetMetrika(date1,date2,url3) {
  var metrika_api_base_url = 'https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/data?oauth_token=<мой токен>&ids=<id моего счётчика>&date1=${date1}&date2=${date2}&dimensions=ym%3As%3AsearchEngine&metrics=ym%3As%3Ausers&filters=ym%3As%3AstartURLPath%3D%3D${url3}&limit=10000';
  metrika_api_base_url = metrika_api_base_url;
  Logger.log(metrika_api_base_url);
  var responseJson=UrlFetchApp.fetch(metrika_api_base_url).getContentText();
  var response = JSON.parse(responseJson);
  Logger.log (responseJson);
  return response;
}
```

Возвращаемая ошибка - недействительный аргумент в строке:

```
var responseJson=UrlFetchApp.fetch(metrika_api_base_url).getContentText();
```

Comment: Обратиться к специалистам за деньги на бирже фриланса. Вам, когда надо зуб удалить, вы же не приходите в ассоциацию стоматологов и просите по быстренькому научить вас удалять зуб.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko прям бизнесмен))

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko это если я хочу, чтобы мне вырвали зуб. А если я вдруг захотел вырвать себе зуб сам, то ситуация уже другая.

Comment: Ну расскажите тогда, как вы будете вырывать себе корневой зуб. К кому обратитесь за советом, что вам на это ответят? Представьте, какие инструменты, знания, медикаменты вам понадобятся. Подумайте о последствиях(поддержке). Также не забудьте тот факт, что вникать во все тонкости вы не хотите.

Comment: А вот вторую часть мне уже парировать нечем.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Хотя у меня ситуация скорее состоит в том, что я умею вырывать зубы собакам, но не умею людям. Теоретически, технология похожа. Но особенностей я не знаю. И тогда я иду к коллеге, который вырывает зубы людям, и задаю соответствующий вопрос. "В чём разница? Какие особенности, и почему я не могу вырвать ему зуб так же, как собаке?". Предположим, что вырывание зубов собакам - это Python. А людям - JS.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. **Если вы "Пробовал .. но чёт не пошло", то очевидно, попробуйте так, чтобы пошло.**

Comment: Ну и что вам ответит ваш коллега? Если он хороший специалист, то он вам ответит тоже самое, что и я. В любом случае, на этом ресурсе вам **помогают** писать код, а не **пишут его за вас**. Приведите пример кода, что, где и как не работает.

Comment: Ну так ведь я задаю конкретный вопрос. У меня нет примера законченного кода, ведь мне нужно сначала сформировать и отправить запрос, а уже потом отформатировать его и использовать как мне там нужно. Я не прошу написать за меня решение. Я прошу сказать, как мне это сделать. Ответ в духе: "Преобразуй в JSON строку, разделяя параметры амперсандом, а потом отправь таким-то методом" - это пример того ответа, который я ищу. Я могу добавить в вопрос условно 2 строки нерабочего когда, но поможет ли это хоть сколько-нибудь?

Comment: Вы добавили код - это хорошо. Я вижу одну ошибку и одну возможную ошибку. Если хотите использовать шаблонный литералы, нужно использовать такие кавычки \`\` а не ''. Затем, запрос скорее всего асинхронный, `var responseJson=UrlFetchApp.fetch(metrika_api_base_url).getContentText();` Здесь возможна ошибка.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko обратные кавычки не ест среда(Google Api Script же). В итоге заменил обычной строкой с конкатенацией. Правда, пришлось ввести переменные, которые бы принимали значения аргументов.
Сейчас напишу в ответ.

Comment: Проблема явно не в Google Apps Script

Comment: @oshliaer у меня ругался на недопустимые символы в строке с обратными кавычками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась заменой шаблонных литералов на обычную строку с конкатенацией и введением дополнительных переменных, принимающих значения аргументов функции(без этого работать отказывалось, возможно проблема в типизации).

В итоге (с того момента я ещё прикрутил получение нужного мне значения из ответа) код выглядит так:

```
function Test2(arg1,arg2,arg3) {
  var date1 = arg1
  var date2 = arg2
  var url3 =  encodeURIComponent(arg3)
  var metrika_api_base_url = "https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/data?oauth_token=<мой токен>&ids=<мой айди>&accuracy=high&date1=" + date1 + "&date2=" + date2 + "&dimensions=ym%3As%3AsearchEngine&metrics=ym%3As%3Ausers&filters=ym%3As%3AstartURLPath%3D%3D'" +url3 + "'&limit=10000";
  metrika_api_base_url = metrika_api_base_url;
  Logger.log(metrika_api_base_url);
  var responseJson=UrlFetchApp.fetch(metrika_api_base_url).getContentText();
  var response = JSON.parse(responseJson);
  var totals = response.totals[0];
  Logger.log (responseJson);
  return response;
}
```